# How to extract and create a .zip file using swift 4 for mac os application?

Tags: swift, macos, zip

i am developing a mac os application. Actually i am downloading a zip file in my mac's document path using an API.

```
let destinationDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            let destination = destinationDir.appendingPathComponent("SomeFileName.zip")
            try data!.write(to: destination)
```

That zip file contains several files and folders and i want to read each files and folder inside that zip file. I also want to create a zip file from disk and upload that to server.
Can anyone suggest me how to read that zip from the disk and extract there.

Answer (score 1):

Since the .zip format is not the same as the zlib - zip is more a container format, containing compressed *entries* (= files) organized in directories - I would suggest to use a zip library, maybe https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation (under MIT license)

There are multiple other implementations, just search for it.